# How to monitor the datasource of wildfly using zabbbix?

Tags: wildfly, datasource, jmx, zabbix

I am trying to monitor my connection between wildfly and my DB with the help of Zabbix. I have used JMX to monitor other components like heap memory etc. And I want to use JMX to monitor the connection. Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you

Comment: did you try with https://docs.tibco.com/pub/mdm/9.2.0/doc/html/GUID-7E2C2C30-50EF-4903-B4FA-EEDF6F457249.html ?

Comment: @IronBishop yes i have and i have successfully connected using jmx also but my main concern is how to monitor the connection of datasource.

Comment: that's kind of an e2e monitor. you can monitor the DB directly with ODBC, and build a wildfly Healtstatus page which will tell you the application connection status, which then you can monitor with Zabbix.